# NFS export a NFS share

Tags: nfs

I already have a NFS share mounted on my server **A** from a remote server **Server-Remote**. (`/mnt/nfs_share`)

On server **A** I installed and run the NFS server service and now I want to export the above share to another server **B** on the network.

After edit `/etc/exports` and run `exportfs -a` on server **A** I got the below error message:

`exportfs: /mnt/nfs_share does not support NFS export`

So is it possible to nfs export an existing NFS share? kind of like a NFS relay or forward?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This is usually not possible except with some insane workarounds because it is a very bad idea.

Comment: Some ancient operating systems used to do this, back in the distant past (SunOS!). It was a nightmare, and was one of the primary causes of entire universities losing all of their workstations and servers at once.... Even if it _were_ possible, it's something you should go out of your way to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to reexport NFS mounts. You can export an NFS mount via SMB however if that works for you.